# How to edit Facebook 'about' information display?

Tags: facebook, facebook-timeline

Can you rotate Facebook "about" information shown under your picture?

At the moment it shows my job, school, and hometown under my profile picture. I would like to have it display my relationship status there, but it is not showing up.

It is set to the friends privacy setting, if that helps.

Comment: Is this information public, or with another setting?